# set default value to date picker at dynamic created form post ajax call

Tags: jquery, angularjs, datepicker

hello friends i am working in angular js , where i have on post ajax call which returns data from which i generate one form ,inside form i have two input fields  which i used as datepickcker

i need to set default values for this date picker i tried by various ways but it didn't work 
i post below my controller code please someone help.

controller

```
function soListCtrl($scope, DTOptionsBuilder, DTColumnBuilder, $http,
    $templateCache, $q) {
    var data = {
        "active": [0, 1]
    };

    agentListJSON = ajaxPost(data, "findAllUsersByType").data;

    var vm = this;
    soPermissions();
    vm.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder
        .fromFnPromise(
            function () {
                var dataToSelectSo = {}
                var nftParentNo = ""
                $(".processingAlert").show();
                var nftParentNo = localStorage.getItem("nftParentNo");
                if (nftParentNo != null) {
                    if (nftParentNo.indexOf('SO') !== -1) {
                        dataToSelectSo = {
                            "soNo": nftParentNo
                        };
                    }
                } else {

                    dataToSelectSo = {
                        "isArchiveList": [1, 11],
                        "allOrOwn": viewSo,
                    };
                    if (isAgentUsr) {
                        dataToSelectSo.isArchiveList = [1, 3, 11]
                        dataToSelectSo.agentIdList = [parseInt($(
                            "#userId").val())]

                    }
                }
                return $http({
                        method: 'POST',
                        url: 'getSoAllDetails',

                        data: dataToSelectSo,
                        headers: {
                            'Accept': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
                            'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8'
                        }
                    })
                    .then(
                        function (response) {
                            $scope.status = response.status;
                            $scope.data = response.data;
                            $scope.salesOrdersJSONList = response.data.data.salesOrdersJSON;
                            if ($scope.salesOrdersJSONList == null) {
                                $scope.salesOrdersJSONList = []
                            }
                            $(".processingAlert").hide();
                            var deferred = $q.defer();
                            deferred
                                .resolve($scope.salesOrdersJSONList);
                            localStorage
                                .removeItem("nftParentNo");
                            return deferred.promise;
                        },
                        function (response) {
                            $scope.data = response.data ||
                                "Request failed";
                            $scope.status = response.status;

                        });

            })
        .withFixedHeader({
            bottom: true
        })
        .withPaginationType('full_numbers')
        .withDataProp('salesOrdersJSONList')
        .withOption('order', [0, 'desc'])
        .withOption('rowCallback', rowCallback)
        .withOption(
            'drawCallback',
            function (settings) {
                if (count < 1) {
                    // onchange='selectStatus1()' onchange="SOByAgent()"

                    $("div.toolbarSO")
                        .html(
                            " <div class='row'> " +
                            "   <div class='col-md-2' >" +
                            "      <div class='form-group'>" +
                            "        <label>Filter:&nbsp;</label>" +
                            "            <select id='fl_status' data-placeholder='Select Status' class='chosen-select form-control'  >" +
                            "              <option value=0></option>" +
                            "              <option value=0>All</option>" +
                            "              <option value='active'>Active</option>" +
                            "              <option value='Unactive'>Unactive</option>" +
                            "              <option value=1>New</option>" +
                            "              <option value=11>In Process</option>" +
                            "              <option value=3>Completed</option>" +
                            "              <option value=18>Archived</option>" +
                            "             <option value='cart'>Cart</option>" +
                            "            </select>" +
                            "       </div>" +
                            "    </div>" +
                            "     <div class='col-md-2'>" +
                            "         <div class='form-group'>" +
                            "          <label>Agent:</label>" +
                            "            <div id='agentListSO'>" +
                            "            </div>" +
                            "         </div>" +
                            "     </div>" +
                            "     <div class='col-md-3'>" +
                            "          <div class='form-group'>" +
                            "            <label>From</label>" +
                            "             <div class='input-daterange input-group' id='datepicker'>" +
                            "                <input type='text' class='form-control' name='start' id='fromallSoDt'/>" +
                            "                  <span class='input-group-addon'>To</span>" +
                            "                  <input type='text' class='form-control' name='end' id='toSoDate'/>" +
                            "             </div>" +
                            "          </div>" +
                            "         </div>" +
                            "     <div class='col-md-3'>" +
                            "    <div class='form-group' style='margin-top:20px'>" +
                            "        <button class='btn btn-info' onClick='getDateWiseSoDetail()'>Submit</button>" +
                            "        <span style='padding-left:10px'>" +
                            "        <button class='btn btn-primary btn-labeled fa fa-refresh' onClick='reserallSO()' id='btn_restSo'>Reset All</button>" +
                            "        </span> " +
                            "          </div>" +
                            " </div>" +
                            " </div>" +
                            "");
                    agentListSO.innerHTML = "";
                    agentListSO.innerHTML = agentListSO.innerHTML +
                        '<select id="ddlagentSO" data-placeholder="Select Agent" class="chosen-select form-control" value="" >';
                    $("#ddlagentSO")
                        .append(
                            '<option class="active-result" value="">' +
                            '</option>' +
                            '<option class="active-result" value="">All' +
                            '</option>');
                    for (var key in agentListJSON.agent) {
                        $("#ddlagentSO").append(
                            '<option class="active-result" value=' +
                            agentListJSON.agent[key].id +
                            '>' +
                            agentListJSON.agent[key].name +
                            '</option>');
                        agentArr.push(agentListJSON.agent[key].id)
                    }
                    $('.chosen-select').chosen();
                    $("#fl_status").val("active").trigger(
                        "chosen:updated");
                    if (isAgentUsr) {
                        $("div.toolbarSO").addClass("hide");
                    }
                }


                var pre = new Date();
                var newd = new Date(pre.setMonth(pre.getMonth() - 3));
                var ddd = newd.getDate();
                var mmm = newd.getMonth() + 1; // January is 0!
                var yyyyy = newd.getFullYear();

                if (ddd < 10) {
                    ddd = '0' + ddd
                }

                if (mmm < 10) {
                    mmm = '0' + mmm
                }

                var td = mmm + '/' + ddd + '/' + yyyyy;

                var pre = td;

                document.getElementById('fromallSoDt').value = formatDate(
                        new Date(getDateFromFormat(td, "mm/dd/yyyy")),
                        "dd MMM, yy");



                $('#fromallSoDt').datepicker({

                    autoclose: true,
                    format: "dd M, yy"
                });










                debugger
                document.getElementById('toSoDate').value = formatDate(
                        new Date(getDateFromFormat(today, "mm/dd/y")),
                        "dd MMM, yy"); 

                $('#toSoDate').datepicker({
                    autoclose: true,
                    format: "dd M, yy"

                });
                // alert(localStorage.getItem("nftParentNo"))
                if (localStorage.getItem("nftParentNo")) {
                    // alert(localStorage.getItem("nftParentNo"));
                    var salesTable1 = $('#salesOrd').DataTable()
                    // salesTable1.search(localStorage.getItem("nftParentNo"));
                }
                count++;
                // alert(JSON.stringify(settings.aoData))
                // console.log(settings.aoData);
                $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
                $('.srate').raty({
                    readOnly: true,
                    cancel: false,
                    half: true,
                    starType: 'i',
                    score: function () {
                        return $(this).attr('data-score');
                    }
                });
                // nft
                /*
                 * if(messageObj.hasOwnProperty('nftType')){ if
                 * (messageObj.nftType = "cntByModule") { // var //
                 * cntByGpByMpListModuleWise=messageObj.cntByGpByMpList;
                 * moduleWiseNft(cntByGpByMpListModuleWise) } }
                 */
                bySubmodule()
                /*
                 * var b=$('#salesOrd') .DataTable() var
                 * a=b.columns().data();
                 */
                if ($('#salesOrd').DataTable().column(6, {
                        filter: 'applied'
                    }).data().length == 0) {
                    document.getElementById('soTotal').textContent = "0/0.00"
                    document.getElementById('soPengPer').textContent = "0%"

                } else {

                    var pendingAmt = $('#salesOrd').DataTable().column(
                        9, {
                            filter: 'applied'
                        }).data().reduce(function (a, b) {
                        return a + b;
                    })
                    var sum = $('#salesOrd').DataTable().column(6, {
                        filter: 'applied'
                    }).data().reduce(function (a, b) {
                        return a + b;
                    })
                    var pendingPer = (pendingAmt / sum) * 100;
                    document.getElementById('soPengPer').textContent = "(" +
                        Math.round(pendingPer) + "%)";
                    document.getElementById('soTotal').textContent = formateAmount(Math
                            .round(pendingAmt)) +
                        "/ " + formateAmount(Math.round(sum));
                }


            })
        .withOption('scrollX', true)
        .withDOM(
            "<'toolbarSO'><'clearfix'><'top'<f><'mar-lft pull-left bottom'i><'mar-lft pull-right bottom'l><'pull-right'p>>rt<'bottom'ipB>")
        .withFixedHeader({
            bottom: true
        });
    vm.dtColumns = [
        DTColumnBuilder
        .newColumn('salesOrders.salesOrderNo')
        .withTitle('SalesOrder No')
        .renderWith(
            function (data, type, full, meta) {
                var status;
                var labelForStatus;
                if (full.length === 0) {
                    return "";
                } else {

                    if (full.salesOrders.isArchived == 1) {
                        var cl = "text-success";
                        labelForStatus = "label label-success";
                        status = "New";
                    } else if (full.salesOrders.isArchived == 18) {
                        var cl = "text-warning";
                        status = "Archived";
                    } else if (full.salesOrders.isArchived == 11) {
                        var cl = "text-faintyellow";
                        status = "In Process";
                    } else if (full.salesOrders.isArchived == 3) {
                        var cl = "text-primary";
                        status = "WO Completed";
                    } else {
                        var cl = "text-info";
                    }
                    var soC = "";
                    if (isCmtsSo == true) {
                        cmtBtnHtml(data, "commentingSO");
                        soC = cmtBtnHtml(data, "commentingSO");
                    }
                    if (isAgentUsr) {
                        return '<div class="row"  style="min-width:222px"><div class="col-md-1" style="padding-top:10px"><span class=" icon-wrap icon-circle ' +
                            cl +
                            '" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="' +
                            status +
                            '"><i class="fa fa-circle"></i></span></div><p class="description col-md-5 pad-top"><strong>' +
                            data + '</strong></d>'; +
                        '</div>';;
                    } else if (full.salesOrders.isArchived == 18) {

                        return '<div class="row"  style="min-width:222px"><div class="col-md-1" style="padding-top:10px"><span class=" icon-wrap icon-circle ' +
                            cl +
                            '" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="' +
                            status +
                            '"><i class="fa fa-circle"></i></span></div><p class="description col-md-5 pad-top"><strong>' +
                            data +
                            '</strong></d>' +
                            nftSignal(data, "notyClassSo") +
                            '</div>' +
                            '</br><div class="btn-group">' +
                            doableSo +
                            deleteSo + printSo + '</div>';

                    } else if (formateAmount(Math
                            .round((full.salesOrders.totalNetAmt - full.otherSODetailsMap.completedAmt))) == 0.00) {
                        return '<div class="row" style="min-width:222px"><div class="col-md-1" style="padding-top:10px"><span class="icon-wrap icon-circle ' +
                            cl +
                            '" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="' +
                            status +
                            '"><i class="fa fa-circle"></i></span></div><p class="description col-md-5 pad-top"><strong>' +
                            data +
                            '</strong></d>' +
                            nftSignal(data, 'notyClassSo') +
                            '</div>' +
                            '</br><div class="btn-group">' +
                            '<a href="#"  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#archiveSO" class="btn mar-smAll btn-sm btn-default archiveSO " id="archive"><i class="fa fa-trash" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Cancel/Archive"></i></a>' +
                            soC + printSo + '</div>';
                    } else {
                        return '<div class="row"   style="min-width:222px"><div class="col-md-1" style="padding-top:10px"><span class="icon-wrap icon-circle ' +
                            cl +
                            '" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="' +
                            status +
                            '"><i class="fa fa-circle"></i></span></div><p class="description col-md-5 pad-top"><strong>' +
                            data +
                            '</strong></d>' +
                            nftSignal(data, "notyClassSo") +
                            '</div>' +
                            '</br><div class="btn-group ">' +
                            doableSo +
                            '<a href="#"  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#archiveSO" class="btn mar-smAll btn-sm btn-default archiveSO" id="archive"><i class="fa fa-trash" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Cancel/Archive"></i></a>' +
                            soC + printSo + '</div>';
                    }
                }
            }),
        DTColumnBuilder
        .newColumn('salesOrders.dueDate')
        .withTitle('Due Date')
        .renderWith(
            function (data, type, full, meta) {
                if (full.length === 0) {
                    return "";
                } else {
                    if (data == null || data.length === 0 ||
                        data === '') {
                        return setDueDtHTML;
                    } else {
                        return '<p id="dd">' +
                            formatDate(new Date(
                                    getDateFromFormat(data,
                                        "y-MM-dd")),
                                "dd-MMM-y") +
                            '</p>' +
                            '<small> (' +
                            getRemaining(formatDate(
                                new Date(
                                    getDateFromFormat(
                                        data,
                                        "y-MM-dd")),
                                "MM/dd/y")) +
                            ')</small>'
                    }
                }
            }),
        DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('salesOrders.orderDate').withTitle(
            'Order Date').renderWith(
            function (data, type, full, meta) {
                if (full.length === 0) {
                    return "";
                } else {
                    if (data == null || data.length === 0 ||
                        data === '') {
                        return "";
                    } else {
                        return formatDate(
                            new Date(getDateFromFormat(
                                full.salesOrders.orderDate,
                                "y-MM-dd")), "dd-MMM-y");

                    }
                }
            }),
        DTColumnBuilder
        .newColumn('salesOrders.orderDate')
        .withTitle('Age (days)')
        .renderWith(
            function (data, type, full, meta) {
                if (full.length === 0) {
                    return "";
                } else {
                    if (data == null || data.length === 0 ||
                        data === '') {
                        return "";
                    } else {

                        return '<p>' +
                            getAge(formatDate(
                                new Date(
                                    getDateFromFormat(
                                        full.salesOrders.orderDate,
                                        "y-MM-dd")),
                                "MM/dd/y")) + '</p>';
                    }
                }
            }),
        DTColumnBuilder
        .newColumn('customerDetailsMap.name')
        .withTitle('Customer Name')
        .renderWith(
            function (data, type, full, meta) {
                if (full.length === 0) {
                    return "";
                } else if (isAgentUsr) {
                    return '<a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#customer" class="customerDetails">' +
                        data + '</a>' + '</br>';
                } else {
                    return '<a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#customer" class="customerDetails">' +
                        data +
                        '</a>' +
                        '</br><div id="srate" class="srate pad-top" data-score="' +
                        full.customerDetailsMap.rating +
                        '"></div>';
                }
            }),
        DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('salesOrders.description').withTitle(
            'Instruction').renderWith(function (data, type, full, meta) {
            if (full.length === 0) {
                return "";
            } else {
                if (data == null || data === 0 || data === '') {
                    return updateInstSo;
                } else {
                    return '<p>' + data + '</d><br><br>' + updateInstSo;
                }
            }
        }),
        DTColumnBuilder
        .newColumn('otherSODetailsMap.discountAmt')
        .withTitle('Total')
        .renderWith(
            function (data, type, full, meta) {
                if (full.length === 0) {
                    return "";
                } else {
                    return '<a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#pend" class="salesDetail">' +
                        formateAmount(Math.round(data)) +
                        '</a>';
                }
            }),
        DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('otherSODetailsMap.qtySum').withTitle(
            'Total Qty').renderWith(function (data, type, full, meta) {
            if (full.length === 0) {
                return "";
            } else {
                return data;
            }
        }),
        DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('otherSODetailsMap.discCompletedAmt')
        .withTitle('Completed').renderWith(
            function (data, type, full, meta) {
                if (full.length === 0) {
                    return "";
                } else {
                    return '<p class="description">' +
                        formateAmount(Math.round(data)) +
                        '</p>';
                }
            }),
        DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('otherSODetailsMap.discPendAmt')
        .withTitle('Pend Amt').renderWith(
            function (data, type, full, meta) {
                if (full.length === 0) {
                    return "";
                } else {
                    return formateAmount(Math.round(data));
                }
            }),
        DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('otherSODetailsMap.pendingQtysum')
        .withTitle('Pend Qty').renderWith(
            function (data, type, full, meta) {
                if (full.length === 0) {
                    return "";
                } else {

                    return data;
                }
            }),
        DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('otherSODetailsMap.pendAmtPer')
        .withTitle('Pend %').renderWith(
            function (data, type, full, meta) {
                if (full.length === 0) {
                    return "";
                } else {
                    return '<p href="#">' + Math.round(data) +
                        '%';
                }
            }),
        DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('otherSODetailsMap.doableQtySum')
        .withTitle('Doable Qty').renderWith(
            function (data, type, full, meta) {
                if (full.length === 0) {
                    return "";
                } else {
                    return '<p>' + data + '</p>';
                }
            }),
        DTColumnBuilder
        .newColumn('otherSODetailsMap.doableAmt')
        .withTitle('Doable Amt')
        .renderWith(
            function (data, type, full, meta) {
                if (full.length === 0) {
                    return "";
                } else {

                    if ((full.salesOrders.totalNetAmt -
                            full.otherSODetailsMap.completedAmt == 0) || full.salesOrders.isArchived == 18) {
                        return data;
                    } else {
                        return formateAmount(Math.round(data)) +
                            '</br><a href=""  data-type="text" data-pk="1" class="allWo11"> </br>' +
                            'All' + '</a>' + ' | ' +
                            chooseSO;
                    }
                }
            }),
        DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('otherSODetailsMap.doable').withTitle(
            'Doable %').renderWith(function (data, type, full, meta) {
            if (full.length === 0) {
                return "";
            } else {
                // alert(data);'<p>'+formateAmount(data)+'</br>(0.00)</p>'+
                return data;
            }
        }),
        DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('customerDetailsMap.createdBy')
        .withTitle('Created By').renderWith(
            function (data, type, full, meta) {
                if (full.length === 0) {
                    return "";
                } else {
                    return '<a href="#">' + data + '</a>';
                }
            }),
        DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('customerDetailsMap.agentName')
        .withTitle('Agent Name').renderWith(
            function (data, type, full, meta) {
                if (full.length === 0) {
                    return "";
                } else {
                    return '<p>' + data + '</p>';
                }
            }),
        DTColumnBuilder
        .newColumn(null)
        .withTitle('')
        .notSortable()
        .renderWith(
            function (data, type, full, meta) {
                if (full.length === 0) {
                    return "";
                } else if (isAgentUsr) {
                    return "";
                } else if (full.salesOrders.isArchived != 1) {
                    return '<a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#soWorkOrders" class="soWorkOrders">' +
                        'work order' +
                        '</a><br>' +
                        '<br>' +
                        '<a class="soInvoice" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#soInvoice">' +
                        'invoices' + '</a>';
                } else {
                    return "";
                }
            })
    ];
    vm.dtInstance = {};
```

"fromallSoDt"" and  "toSoDate" are my two date pickers fields
i need answer of following?

1) need to set today's value for "toSoDate" and for "fromallSoDt" needs to set previous six month value

2) on click submit button i have another function call , which also get data and bind to below data table , when i click submit automatically this date pickers value set to previous values which are i set in above code

```
var pre = new Date();
                var newd = new Date(pre.setMonth(pre.getMonth() - 3));
                var ddd = newd.getDate();
                var mmm = newd.getMonth() + 1; // January is 0!
                var yyyyy = newd.getFullYear();

                if (ddd < 10) {
                    ddd = '0' + ddd
                }

                if (mmm < 10) {
                    mmm = '0' + mmm
                }

                var td = mmm + '/' + ddd + '/' + yyyyy;

                var pre = td;

                document.getElementById('fromallSoDt').value = formatDate(
                        new Date(getDateFromFormat(td, "mm/dd/yyyy")),
                        "dd MMM, yy");



                $('#fromallSoDt').datepicker({

                    autoclose: true,
                    format: "dd M, yy"
                });


debugger
                var today = new Date();
                var dd = today.getDate();
                var mm = today.getMonth() + 1; // January is 0!
                var yyyy = today.getFullYear();

                if (dd < 10) {
                    dd = '0' + dd
                }

                if (mm < 10) {
                    mm = '0' + mm
                }

                today = mm + '/' + dd + '/' + yyyy;
                $('#fromallSoDt').datepicker({

                    autoclose: true,
                    format: "dd M, yy"
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to set value like this

```
var d = new Date();
var currMonth = d.getMonth();
var currYear = d.getFullYear();
var startDate = new Date(currYear, currMonth, 1);

 $('#fromallSoDt').datepicker({
   autoclose: true,
   format: "dd M, yy"
   });

 $('#fromallSoDt').datepicker("setDate", startDate);
```

Comment: hello @KishoreKumar Mani i worked with above it binds 01 Mar, 18 .. why thi happen any clue ?

Answer (score -1):

```
var today = new Date();
            var dd = today.getDate();
            var mm = today.getMonth() + 1; // January is 0!
            var yyyy = today.getFullYear();

            if (dd < 10) {
                dd = '0' + dd
            }

            if (mm < 10) {
                mm = '0' + mm
            }

            today = dd + '/' + mm + '/' + yyyy;

            $('#toSoDate').datepicker({
                autoclose: true,

                format: "dd M, yyyy"

            }); 
    $('#toSoDate').datepicker("setDate", next);
```

hie i found this solution with help of @KishoreKumar Mani , thanku